# Is setNeedsDisplay *always* repainting?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, custom-view, setneedsdisplay

I wrote a little custom-view-application using cocoa. And later (yes, i know it's bad) I just asked myself: Would this work for cocoa touch as well? Of course id did not work instantly, I had to change the class names and so on. Well, i refreshed the View, whenever it was needed, using a `NSTimer` and the `setNeedsDisplay:` method. Worked pretty well under cocoa, but absolutely not under cocoa touch.

I can't explain it to myself an I actually don't know what lines of code could help someone to solve the problem. Maybe here is the Timer:

```
[self setMyTimer: [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.03 target:self selector:@selector(myTarget:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]];
```

And it's target:

```
- (void) myTarget:(NSTimer *)timer {
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

The timer is invoked every 30 ms, I checked that with an NSLog.

In the `drawRect:` method I did actually just draw some shapes and did nothing else. Just in case it would be necessary to call some kind of `clearRect:` method. As I said, under cocoa it worked.

Comment: Try `[self setNeedsDisplay:YES];`.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/875110/setneedsdisplay-doesnt-always-call-drawrect

Comment: @WTP: This appears to be on the iPhone, which does not have the `setNeedsDisplay:` method, and only has the argument-less `setNeedsDisplay` (which really makes sense, because I don't think I have ever written `setNeedsDisplay:NO` except one time when I was curious if it even did anything).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first verify whether `drawRect:` is running by using a breakpoint or log statement.

Then, make sure that your view is actually on the screen. What is the value of `[self superview]`? You should also do something like `self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];` so that you can see where your view is.

Just because you're marking the view dirty every 30ms doesn't mean it will draw every 30ms. It generally should (that's about 30fps), but there isn't a guarantee. `drawRect:` shouldn't rely on how often it's called. From your question, I assume you mean that it's never drawing, rather than just not drawing as often as expected.

Comment: Actually, I forgot to mention that: The view is drawn once, on setup. I suppose this requires the view to be on the screen, doesn't it? After the initialization of the custom view the the drawRect:-method is never called again.
I just tried to get the value of [self superview] by calling `NSLog(@"%@", [self superview]);`. This printed (null) to the console. Looks like a clue, but does not show me the solution.

Comment: This means you're no longer onscreen. Implement `willMoveToSuperview:` to find out when you're being removed.

Comment: Betcha there are two different instances of the view class, one sitting idly onscreen and the other getting updated.

Comment: @Chuck's suggestion is a very common problem and you should definitely check it out.

Comment: @Valentin Rüchardt: The first step in investigating @Chuck's suggestion is to log the pointer value (`%p`, which produces something like `0xd3c2b1a0`) of `self` in `didMoveToSuperview` and in `setMyTimer:`. If the two methods log different pointer values, that tells you that you created two separate views, and the one that's in the view hierarchy (and, as such, able to draw) is not the one you are giving a timer.

Comment: **2011-09-07 14:03:29.762 SimpleGame[2620:b303] didMoveToSuperview: 0x4b40080

2011-09-07 14:03:29.770 SimpleGame[2620:b303] After instancing the NSTimer: 0x4b40080**

These two results look pretty much the same...

Answer (score 3):

Here's the discussion about `setNeedsDisplay` (note the LACK of arguments) from the documentation of `UIView`:

> You can use this method to notify the system that your view’s contents
>   need to be redrawn. This method makes a note of the request and
>   returns control back to your code immediately. The view is not
>   actually redrawn until the next drawing cycle, at which point all
>   invalidated views are updated.
>
> You should use this method to request that a view be redrawn only when
>   the content or appearance of the view change. If you simply change the
>   geometry of the view, the view is typically not redrawn. Instead, its
>   existing content is adjusted based on the value in the view’s
>   `contentMode` property. Redisplaying the existing content improves
>   performance by avoiding the need to redraw content that has not
>   changed.

In contrast, here's the discussion about `setNeedsDisplay:` (note the argument) from the documentation of `NSView`:

> Whenever the data or state used for drawing a view object changes, the
>   view should be sent a `setNeedsDisplay:` message. `NSView` objects marked
>   as needing display are automatically redisplayed on each pass through
>   the application’s event loop. (View objects that need to redisplay
>   before the event loop comes around can of course immediately be sent
>   the appropriate display... method.)

Comment: I am not sure im on the right track, but isn't NSView the cocoa-style view? I'm actually in cocoa touch, where the custom views i added in Interface Builder showed me, they were UIViews. So i picked the UIView-class as inheritance class (sorry, english is not my mother tongue. I'm talking about the class, my class is inheriting from.) Actually, there is no method setNeedsDisplay: in the UIView.

Comment: @Valentin: As the post reads, `UIView` has `setNeedsDisplay` and `NSView` has `setNeedsDisplay:`. The former is for iOS and the latter is for OSX.

Comment: Ah sorry, I did read that over. But what does this tell me? So I put a request to be redrawn in the drawing cycle. How fast does this one repeat?