# setNeedsDisplay() is not calling draw(_ rect: CGRect)

Tags: ios, swift

I found similar questions in this website but none of them solved my issue. Please carefully read the whole code. The `setNeedsDisplay()` function is not calling the `draw(_ rect: CGRect)` when I want to draw a line on MyView.

I created a view called "**myView**" in storyboard as sub View of "**MyViewController**" and created a `IBOutlet` to the view controller.

Then I created a class called "MyViewClass" and set it as the class of "myView" in storyboard.

I set the bool value drawLine to true and call function `updateLine()`,
the problem is the `setNeedsDispaly()` is not triggering the `draw(_ rect: CGRect)` function.

```
import UIKit

class MyViewClass : UIView{

    var drawLine = Bool() // decides whether to draw the line
    func updateLine(){
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        if drawLine == true{
            guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else{
                return
            }
            context.setLineWidth(4.0)
            context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
            context.move(to: CGPoint(x: 415 , y: 650))
            context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:415 , y: 550))
            context.strokePath()
        }

    }
}
class myViewController:UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var insideView: UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        let myViewInstance = MyViewClass()
        myViewInstance.drawLine = true
        myViewInstance.updateLine()
    }
}
```

I'm fairly new to Swift. Any help will appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: please have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/876033/4056108). I have tried it myself and it feels like if the view is not visible it will not call drawRect. Just confirm your that the view you are planning to update is visible when the set the drawLine bool to true.

Comment: The view is never added to your view hierarchy therefore it will never get drawn.

Comment: can you tell me how do I add this to View Hierarchy, Do I just add the View to the main View? because I already do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 issues:

1. you're not giving the new view a `frame` so it defaults to zero width and zero height
2. you're not adding the view to the view heirarchy

   ```
   let myViewInstance = MyViewClass(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: view.bounds.height))
   myViewInstance.backgroundColor = .white  // you might want this a well
   myViewInstance.drawLine = true
   self.view.addSubview(myViewInstance)
   myViewInstance.updateLine()
   ```

---

A cleaner way to have your view redraw when a property (such as `drawLine`) is changed is to use a property observer:

```
var drawLine: Bool = true {
    didSet {
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

That way, the view will automatically redraw when you change a property and then you don't need `updateLine()`.

Note that `setNeedsDisplay` just schedules the view for redrawing.  If you set this on every property, the view will only redraw once even if multiple properties are changed.

---

**Note:** `viewDidLoad()` would be a more appropriate place to add your line because it is only called once when the `view` is created.  `viewWillAppear()` is called anytime the `view` appears so it can be called multiple times (for instance in a `UITabView`, `viewWillAppear()` is called every time the user switches to that tab).

Comment: Thanks @vacawama, this fixed my problem. Greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

MyView class

```
class myView : UIView {
    var updateView : Bool = false {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        print("in Draw")

    }

}
```

MyViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        let view = myView()
        view.updateView = true
    }
}
```

In the storyboard i had setup the view class as myView therefore its visible.

[image: StoryBoard Image]

[image: Output Image]

Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate reply, Do I have to  make a IBOutlet to this view? or can I just add subviews to the instance of this view class?

Comment: @JohnXavier i haven't made outlet of the view.

Comment: Thangs again @chirag90, your answer is also correct, appreciate it.